# How to exclude table from certain styles

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a `<table>` that I am trying to make mobile-friendly with some CSS. However, I **do not** want this 'mobile-friendly' CSS to apply to all our tables. The CSS should not be applied to tables that have the class `no-wrap`. All of the tables we use have the class `.table2`. We also have a lot of nested tables. And these nested tables are the main problem. Here is [an example with jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/378ktzjy/).

As you can see in the example, the first table has 2 classes; `table2` and `no-wrap`. I do not want to apply the 'mobile-friendly' CSS to tables that have the `no-wrap` class. So the first example works fine because the CSS is not applied. However, the second table also has the `no-wrap` class, but I guess because it is nested inside another table (that also has the class `table2`), it does not look at the `:not(.no-wrap)` selector and the CSS **is** applied.

Code for reference:

```css
.table2 {
  color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-spacing: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

  .track table.table2:not(.no-wrap),
  .track .table2:not(.no-wrap) thead,
  .track .table2:not(.no-wrap) tbody,
  .track .table2:not(.no-wrap) th,
  .track .table2:not(.no-wrap) td,
  .track .table2:not(.no-wrap) tr {
    display: block;
  }


  .track .table2:not(.no-wrap) tr {
    margin: 20px;
  }

  .track .table2:not(.no-wrap) tr[height] {
    height: 0;
  }

  .track .table2:not(.no-wrap) td {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="track">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table2 no-wrap">
    <tbody>
      <tr height="19">
        <td width="170"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td width="80"></td>
        <td width="80"></td>
        <td width="80"></td>
        <td width="80"></td>
        <td width="100"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle">Artikel</td>
        <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle">Omschrijving</td>
        <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle" align="right">Aantal&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle" align="right">Bruto prijs&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle" align="right">Netto prijs&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle" align="right">Kostprijs&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle">&nbsp;BTW</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpAll trackFormBodyCellLink">
          <font size="2">BBA</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB">
          <font size="2">Bezoek Bedrijfsarts</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB" align="right">
          <font size="2">1,000</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB" align="right">
          <font size="2">175,00</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB" align="right">
          <font size="2">175,00</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB" align="right">
          <font size="2">100,00</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB">
          <font size="2">Hoog-tarief</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpLRB">&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB">&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpLRB trackFormBodyCellLink">
          <font size="2">REISKOSTEN</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB">
          <font size="2">Reiskosten</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">
          <font size="2">1,000</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">
          <font size="2">75,00</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">
          <font size="2">75,00</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">
          <font size="2">0,00</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB">
          <font size="2">Geen</font>&nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <div style="margin: 100px 0;">
  <hr />
  </div>
  
  
  <table class="table2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table2 no-wrap">
          <tbody>
            <tr height="19">
              <td width="170"></td>
              <td></td>
              <td width="80"></td>
              <td width="80"></td>
              <td width="80"></td>
              <td width="80"></td>
              <td width="100"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle">Artikel</td>
              <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle">Omschrijving</td>
              <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle" align="right">Aantal&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle" align="right">Bruto prijs&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle" align="right">Netto prijs&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle" align="right">Kostprijs&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="trackFormHeaderTitle">&nbsp;BTW</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpAll trackFormBodyCellLink">
                <font size="2">BBA</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB">
                <font size="2">Bezoek Bedrijfsarts</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB" align="right">
                <font size="2">1,000</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB" align="right">
                <font size="2">175,00</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB" align="right">
                <font size="2">175,00</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB" align="right">
                <font size="2">100,00</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpTRB">
                <font size="2">Hoog-tarief</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpLRB">&nbsp;</td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB">&nbsp;</td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpLRB trackFormBodyCellLink">
                <font size="2">REISKOSTEN</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB">
                <font size="2">Reiskosten</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">
                <font size="2">1,000</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">
                <font size="2">75,00</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">
                <font size="2">75,00</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB" align="right">
                <font size="2">0,00</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="inpRB">
                <font size="2">Geen</font>&nbsp;
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Your CSS works but I'd use `.table2 .table2` as the safer alternative.

Comment: My CSS ***does not work***. Otherwise I wouldn't ask the question to begin with. Since in my example the second table still has the styles applied which I do not want. Using `.table2 .table2` is an option for tables nested 1 layer, but what if it goes deeper? Then it will not work again...

Comment: *"The CSS should not be applied to tables that have the class no-wrap."* That's confusing because you say, *"However, the second table also has the no-wrap class, but I guess because it is nested inside another table (that also has the class table2), it does not look at the :not(.no-wrap) selector and the CSS is applied."* If you didn't want any styles on nested table wouldn't simply `.no-wrap` do the job? `:not(.no-wrap)` would negate `.no-wrap` which you don't want since `.no-wrap` supposedly removes the mobile styles. BTW it would be helpful if you added `.no-wrap` to the OP code.

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks for your answer. Then maybe something else is broken. Fact of the matter is, in my code example included in the post, I have 2 tables. **Both** have the `no-wrap` class. But only 1 table (the first one) is negating the styles like it should. The second one is still wrapping everything (so `:not(.no-wrap)` clearly doesn't work on the second table). Also `.no-wrap` is not a class that contains any styles. It is purely used in the `:not()` selector to negate the styles in my example when the screen is < 1024px, but it is only working for the first table, not the second one...

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

- Don't use `:not()` because it's [quirks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#description) make it unreliable and difficult with nested selectors.
- Use an additional class to the other `<table>`s (ex. `.wrap`) and make it diametrically oppose `.no-wrap`.
- Do not use a class that both types of `<table>` share (ie `.table2`).

### Other Problems

- `<font>` is HTML4 not HTML5, use a `<span>` and apply CSS to it.
- Attributes `cellspacing`, `cellpadding`, `bgcolor`, and `align` are deprecated. Use CSS properties [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing), `padding`, `background-color`, and `text-align`.

In the example, there are 2 `<table>`s with `.no-wrap` (one of them is nested within another `<table>`) and 2 `<table>`s with `.wrap` (one of them is also nested within another `<table>`).

```css
.table2 {
  color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-spacing: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

tbody > tr:first-of-type {height: 19px}

tr, td {outline: 1px dashed red;} 

.wrap {outline: 3px dotted cyan}

.no-wrap {outline: 3px dotted lime}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  table.wrap,
  table.wrap > :is(thead, tbody, tfoot),
  table.wrap > :is(thead, tbody, tfoot) > tr,
  table.wrap > :is(thead, tbody, tfoot) > tr > :is(th, td) {display: block}
  table.wrap > :is(thead, tbody, tfoot) > tr {margin: 20px}
  table.wrap > tbody > tr:first-of-type {height:0}
  table.wrap > :is(thead, tbody, tfoot) > tr > td {position:relative;margin:5px 0}

  table.no-wrap,
  table.no-wrap > :is(thead, tbody, tfoot),
  table.no-wrap > :is(thead, tbody, tfoot) > tr,
  table.no-wrap > :is(thead, tbody, tfoot) > tr > :is(th, td) {display: default;}
  table.no-wrap > :is(thead, tbody, tfoot) > tr {margin: 0;}
  table.no-wrap > tbody > tr:first-of-type {height: 19px;}
  table.no-wrap > :is(thead, tbody, tfoot) > tr > td {position: static;margin: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="track">
  <table class="table2 no-wrap">
  <tbody> <tr> <td width="170"></td> <td></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="100"></td> </tr> <tr> <td>Artikel</td> <td>Omschrijving</td> <td align="right">Aantal&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Bruto prijs&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Netto prijs&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Kostprijs&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;BTW</td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span>BBA</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Bezoek Bedrijfsarts</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>1,000</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>175,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>175,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>100,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Hoog-tarief</span>&nbsp; </td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span>REISKOSTEN</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Reiskosten</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>1,000</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>75,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>75,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>0,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Geen</span>&nbsp; </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> <hr />
  <table class="table2"> <tr> <td> 
  <table class="table2 no-wrap"> <tbody> <tr> <td width="170"></td> <td></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="100"></td> </tr> <tr> <td>Artikel</td> <td>Omschrijving</td> <td align="right">Aantal&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Bruto prijs&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Netto prijs&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Kostprijs&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;BTW</td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span>BBA</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Bezoek Bedrijfsarts</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>1,000</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>175,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>175,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>100,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Hoog-tarief</span>&nbsp; </td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span>REISKOSTEN</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Reiskosten</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>1,000</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>75,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>75,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>0,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Geen</span>&nbsp; </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> </tr> </table> <hr> 
  <table class="table2 wrap"> 
  <tbody> <tr> <td width="170"></td> <td></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="100"></td> </tr> <tr> <td>Artikel</td> <td>Omschrijving</td> <td align="right">Aantal&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Bruto prijs&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Netto prijs&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Kostprijs&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;BTW</td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span>BBA</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Bezoek Bedrijfsarts</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>1,000</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>175,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>175,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>100,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Hoog-tarief</span>&nbsp; </td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span>REISKOSTEN</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Reiskosten</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>1,000</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>75,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>75,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>0,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Geen</span>&nbsp; </td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
  <table class="table2"> <tr> <td> 
  <table class="table2 wrap"> <tbody> <tr> <td width="170"></td> <td></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="80"></td> <td width="100"></td> </tr> <tr> <td>Artikel</td> <td>Omschrijving</td> <td align="right">Aantal&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Bruto prijs&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Netto prijs&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">Kostprijs&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;BTW</td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span>BBA</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Bezoek Bedrijfsarts</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>1,000</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>175,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>175,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>100,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Hoog-tarief</span>&nbsp; </td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td align="right">&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td> <span>REISKOSTEN</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Reiskosten</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>1,000</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>75,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>75,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td align="right"> <span>0,00</span>&nbsp; </td> <td> <span>Geen</span>&nbsp; </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> </tr> </table>
</div>
```